# I want to update API through my rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application I am attempting to send a PUT request like

```
uri = URI.parse("{server}//#{$STATS_APP_URL}/api/sport_configs/sport_config_entry/#{self.id}")
request = Net::HTTP::Put.new(uri.path)
```

However, the request is appearing as a POST (instead of a PUT) to the application running on the server. How can I send an actual PUT instead?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I edited this to try to save it from being closed. We still need to know more about the code running on the server end, but the question is pretty clearly "How do I send a PUT instead of a POST"?

Comment: @jdl exactly what i am searching for, the request is appearing as a POST (instead of a PUT)